# How to aggregate on 2 levels and keep the Docs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is something i use to do with Elasticsearch, but i can't find how to do that with MongoDB.

Here is a collection Animals:

```
[
  { kind: "Dog", owner: "John", name: "Max" },
  { kind: "Dog", owner: "John", name: "Buddy" },
  { kind: "Dog", owner: "John", name: "Cooper" },
  { kind: "Cat", owner: "John", name: "Charlie" },
  { kind: "Dog", owner: "Peter", name: "Jack" },
]
```

Here is the result i am expecting:

```
{
  Dog: {
    John: [
      { kind: "Dog", owner: "John", name: "Max" },
      { kind: "Dog", owner: "John", name: "Buddy" },
      { kind: "Dog", owner: "John", name: "Cooper" },
    ],
    Peter: [
      { kind: "Dog", owner: "Peter", name: "Jack" },
    ]
  }
  Cat: {
    John: [
      { kind: "Cat", owner: "John", name: "Charlie" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea to do that?  I have experimented some aggregates with `$group` and `$push` but i can't build this "nested" level Animal/Owner/Documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

Nested Array Structure

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$group":{"_id":{"kind":"$kind","owner":"$owner"},"docs":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.kind","ownerbykind":{"$push":{"owner":"$_id.owner","docs":"$docs"}}}}
])
```

OR

Use `$mergeObjects` with `$arrayToObject` to produce the desired structure.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$group":{"_id":{"kind":"$kind","owner":"$owner"},"a":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.kind","b":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id.owner","$a"]]]}}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":null,"c":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id","$b"]]]}}}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$c"}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks you saved my day! The second query doesn't work with my real case because ``owner`` et ``kind`` are ``ObjectIds`` and not string (``$arrayToObject`` throw an error), but the first one make the job !